# how to solve squash error on ubuntu 16.04 version?

Tags: 16.04

Actually I've installed the software using bootable usb after completion of installation it shows errors that filled my screen and that made to me restart forcefully.[Squash error and print request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3YmZ.jpg)

Comment: Sum checks the iso

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  The squashfs refers to a squashed (compressed or reduced in size) file system; the errors are because it contains lots of errors. As @Panther suggested; you should check your download was successful (ie. no errors) via steps you can see on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto